# How to run db scripts after installation and update of the phonegap android application

Tags: android, cordova

I am making a phonegap android app which will be a offline application.So my data for the app will be populated from the local storage.

**Now i want to run the db scripts when the application is installed for the fist time and also whenever the user updates the app via app store.**

Please suggest me ways to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only done this using a WebSQL database, but basically you write your JS to do the following:

onDeviceReady
 - check for data in database
   - if no data is found then
     - run CREATE TABLE SQL statement
     - run INSERT SQL statement containing your default data

See here for an example: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/8/14/Updating-PhoneGap-Databases

Comment: Thanx Sam,it helped and the link u provided helped me a lot.